# extjs combobox loading values from controller

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, combobox

I have a ext js combobox the values of which I am loading from my controller. the following is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   Ext.onReady(function () {
   var combo = Ext.data.Record.create([

        {
            name: 'Name',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ]);

    var writer = new Ext.data.JsonWriter({
        encode: false,
        listful: true,
        writeAllFields: true
    });

    var reader = new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        totalProperty: 'total',
        successProperty: 'success',
        idProperty: 'Name',
        root: 'data',
        messageProperty: 'message'  // <-- New "messageProperty" meta-data
    }, combo);


    var proxy = new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        api: {
            read: '/ComboBox/Load'

        },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' }
    });

    var store = new Ext.data.Store({
        id: 'Name',
        proxy: proxy,

        reader: reader,
        writer: writer,  // <-- plug a DataWriter into the store just as you would a Reader
        autoSave: false // <-- false would delay executing create, update, destroy requests until specifically told to do so with some [save] buton.

    });

    store.load();


    Ext.data.DataProxy.addListener('exception', function (proxy, type, action, options, res) {
        Ext.Msg.show({
            title: 'ERROR',
            msg: res.message,
            icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
            buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
        });
    });

    var editor = new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({
        saveText: 'Update'
    });

    var numberField = new Ext.form.ComboBox({
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        hiddenName: 'Name',
        store:store,
        displayField: 'Name',
        typeAhead: true,
        mode: 'local',
        triggerAction: 'all',
        emptyText: 'Choose number...',
        selectOnFocus: true,
        pageSize: 50,
        labelWidth: 50,
        width: 300,
        padding: '60 0 0 0',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
})
```

In my controller I have a load function

```
    public JsonResult Load()
    {
        List<string> my_values = new List<string>();
        my_values.Add("aaaa");
        my_values.Add("bbbb");
        my_values.Add("cccc");
        my_values.Add("dddd");
        my_values.Add("eeee");
        return Json(new
        {
            total = my_values.Count,
            data = my_values,
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

However my combobox is always empty and does not load the values.What am I doing wrong?Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of issues with your code that you can see via Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools.  The first one is Ext.data.Record.create is giving the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined
```

Some Ext.js tutorials have the Ext.data.Record.create way mentioned (including the documentation) but there is a much simpler way of setting up the entire thing.  I'm only going to focus on the reading/loading part.

**In the Javascript:**, I changed things to match the Ext.JS 4 way of setting things up:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.define('combo', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: [
                { name: 'Name', type: 'string' }
            ]
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'combo',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: '/Combo/Load',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'data',
                    totalProperty: 'total'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        });

        var numberField = new Ext.form.field.ComboBox({
            fieldLabel: 'Name',
            store: store,
            displayField: 'Name',
            typeAhead: true,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'Name',
            valueField: 'Name',
            triggerAction: 'all',
            emptyText: 'Choose number...',
            selectOnFocus: true,
            pageSize: 50,
            labelWidth: 50,
            width: 300,
            padding: '60 0 0 0',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });       
});
```

You now have a model you can reuse in other areas as well as your proxy and reader simplified.

**In the MVC Controller**, instead of dealing with loading an array, I changed it to have DTO class, so we get a property: value pair.  It is much easier to setup the Ext.JS reader to map json data objects than a single array of strings.  Plus this way will help you expand to handle the name/value pairs that most selection fields will have.

```
public class Combo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Combo(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public JsonResult Load()
{
    List<Combo> my_values = new List<Combo>();
    my_values.Add(new Combo("aaaa"));
    my_values.Add(new Combo("bbbb"));
    my_values.Add(new Combo("cccc"));
    my_values.Add(new Combo("dddd"));
    my_values.Add(new Combo("eeee"));

    return Json(new
    {
        total = my_values.Count,
        data = my_values,
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I am getting a blank page without any combobox when i used this code.

Comment: Try url: '/ComboBox/Load' instead of the /Combo/Load I have up there.  Sorry, I setup my test Controller with a different name when I was testing.

Comment: ok I had modified that before trying...however when i changed the list structure to object as u suggested, my code worked with the previous aspx.Now I am able to see the values in combobox..Now I want to get the selected value and pass it to my controller. How do I do this.I have tried adding listener to combo..but not sure how to pass the value to controller.       listeners:{
                select : function(combo, record, index){
                    var value = combo.getValue();
                    alert(value + ' clicked');
                    
                   
                }

Comment: It depends on how you are going to send the value to the server  If it is via regular form post (perhaps with a submit button), then you can use the 'name' setting in the Ext.form.field.ComboBox (or any Ext.form.field component) to set the name of the form key for the ComboBox when the form posts.  If you are doing it via Ajax, then you already know how to get the value via combo.getValue() so you'd use it with http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.Ajax